# Only partial rendering of Vray material (3ds max)

Tags: 3d, 3dsmax

So I'm having trouble rendering the material on a strip of wood.

I've loaded a wood texture onto what will be the outer edge of a tabletop.
I took a circular spline, extruded, manually added more horizontal segments, and then loaded the material library and its respective maps.

for some reason the lighting is working even in preview.

I'm sure this is a simple problem,However this is literally the first time I've tried to texture something, so I have no idea what to do to fix it.[image]

Answer (score 0):

You should create a material, with the wood texture in the diffuse channel. Apply that material to the object.
Am I understanding the question correctly?